When deploying a Git repo via cPanel, how to return an error to the browser
I currently have a .cpanel.yml file which runs a bash script which, amongst other things, updates some dependencies via Composer.
This all works fine!
However, if Composer throws an error, the cPanel UI wasn't showing this, it was giving me the green panel, saying all went well. Which makes sense really, as my script wasn't doing anything with the result of the Composer command!
So I added a check for $? after the composer install command, and if it's non-zero, exit the script with that error code.
php -d allow_url_fopen=1 -d zend.detect_unicode=0 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

composer_exit_code=$?

if [[ $composer_exit_code -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Composer failed with error code ${composer_exit_code}"
    exit $composer_exit_code;
fi

Now the bash script, and therefore the .cpanel.yml execution, will exit with an error code if Composer encounters any issues.
This kind of works, because the deploy script exits there and doesn't go further, which is good! However, the cPanel UI now just hangs, forever saying the deployment is queued.
I've tried various things to get cPanel to show an error here, even just doing exit 128 in the .cpanel.yml file, but anything other than letting it end normally (or doing exit 0) causes the cPanel UI to hang.
Looking at the browser's Developer Tools > Network tab, I can even see that the server sends the output from the execution of .cpanel.yml to the browser, but the JS on the client side doesn't know what to do with this (it's expecting JSON) so we just get a console error.
So my question is, does anyone know how to get a deploy script error to show up in the cPanel UI?
